# svn: Path does not exist in revision

Tags: svn, msbuild, copy

I want to create tag in subversion. On the command line I have tried the following:

**svn copy http://myserver.mycompany.com:8080/svn/SVN_Main/trunk http://myserver.mycompany.com:8080/svn/SVN_Main/tag/Build-5.4.3.2 -m "Build 5.4.3.2 tag"**

I get this error:

**svn: Path 'http://myserver.mycompany.com:8080/svn/SVN_Main/trunk' does not exist for revision 1234**

The path http://myserver.mycompany.com:8080/svn/SVN_Main/trunk is exact same path that I have when I use the repro-browser on that folder. Any ideas on what may be causing this problem? I have also tried it w/wo username/password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens if you just do the copy from within the repository browser (right click on the folder, then copy)

Could it also be a case-sensitivity issue?  We run our svn server under Apache on Windows  and find that reads are general case-insensitive, but write operations are case sensitive.

This is a real pain if a developer checks out /trunk/somefolder when the name is really /trunk/SomeFolder.  They will get an error only when trying to commit.

Comment: That was it. I had "trunk" instead of "Trunk"

Answer (score 1):

Either that isn't the right path, or you've put a `-r` option in there that you didn't show. Try a `svn ls` on that path to confirm it is correct. If you passed `-r`, make sure you've used the right revision.