# SVN: Move pending changes to a new branch

Tags: svn, version-control, branch

Source code has local modifications that must not be committed to the trunk, but rather to a branch that does not yet exist.

This is what `svn info` shows:

```
Pfad: .
URL: svn://10.8.0.1/fx_dev
Basis des Projektarchivs: svn://10.8.0.1/fx_dev
UUID des Projektarchivs: 6279aca8-1485-11de-bcb4-29f147300bdb
Revision: 859
Knotentyp: Verzeichnis
Plan: normal
Letzter Autor: andy_svn
Letzte geänderte Rev: 859
Letztes Änderungsdatum: 2010-12-02 15:08:11 +0100 (Do, 02. Dez 2010)
```

(It's German, but I guess you still understand it)

How can I create a branch and move the pending changes onto that branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem now: The server-side directory structure was completely wrong and missing the TTB (trunk, tags, branches) directories. I changed that and now everything's fine!

I didn't know trunk, tags and branches were actual directories in the repo everybody could add and delete, I always thought they were immutably provided by SVN.

Answer (score 44):

Create a branch via

```
svn copy URL/trunk URL/branches/B_NAME -m"- New Branch"
```

make an

```
svn switch URL/branches/B_NAME
```

and then **commit your changes**.

This works because the copy happens on the server, not the client. The `svn switch` command will not overwrite changes locally when switching over to the new branch.

Comment: I now tried `svn copy svn://10.8.0.1/fx_dev/trunk svn://10.8.0.1/fx_dev/branches/sidebar -m"- New Branch"` - this is similar to the commands I had tried after reading the docs. I get: `svn: Path »svn://10.8.0.1/fx_dev/trunk« does not exist in revision 863` (error message translated from German, might not be exactly the same in English).

Comment: I even tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344257/svn-path-does-not-exist-in-revision No improvement :-(

Comment: Is it possible that the server has a completely wrong directory structure? This document (http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/misc/svn01/) states one *should* setup the directory structure like that, but it obviously can be done differently? And what is the difference between a repository and a project?

Comment: Alright, that was it. SVN server-side setup completely screwed up :D

Comment: @khmarbaise why not copy/commit from the WC directly into a new branch? I've never tried it, but if it's possible as `svn help copy` claims it is, it would be a lot easier, no?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much everything you ever need to know about SVN is in the red book (linked). Unless you have a specific question, maybe saying what you have tried already, it is what you should refer to.

Create a branch

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04s02.html#svn-ch-4-sect-2.1

the svn switch command

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re27.html

Comment: Will that create the new branch?  or will he have to create the branch with an svn copy and then call svn switch?

Comment: Those URL's you are referencing for the Subversion book are for versions of Subversion that are over 5 years old.  Google has a nasty habit of pulling up the oldest versions of the SVN Book.  Be careful when using Google and it's Subversion Book links.